# puppetdb fails to start with no clear error message

Tags: puppet, postgresql, puppetdb

Our puppetdb instance failed after a long time running just fine. After restarting the server and trying to start puppetdb using `service puppetdb start` We are seeing all the normal output of a successful db bootstrap yet the service stays in a `not running` state.

There was a pretty huge stacktrace with failed SQL statements running on the db and this very peculiar error -

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
  Detail: Escape sequence "\�" is invalid.
  Where: JSON data, line 1: ...});return x(a)};var Hd=/[\\\\[\\\\].#$\\\\/\\\�...
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
  Detail: Escape sequence "\�" is invalid.
  Where: JSON data, line 1: ...});return x(a)};var Hd=/[\\\\[\\\\].#$\\\\/\\\�..
```

I also see the postgresdb puppet uses throws alot of these errors - `could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer`, which weren't there until the crash happened.

Anyone has a clue on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Look in your postgres logs and see if they  provide any more info. Do you use your puppetdb to export resources ?

Comment: Sadly, the postgres error I've attached is all I have in the logs. Also, to the best of my knowledge we are not exporting resources.

Comment: Are you sure you looked in your postgres logs, it's normally quite vocal when it encounters an issue /var/lib/pgsql/.../data/pg_log/* .